# lista de usuários socketio nodejs

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Estou usando os seguintes scripts abaixo para armazenar uma lista de usuários que estão logados no chat que estou fazendo em socket.io e nodejs,porém eu queria armazenar mais de um objeto,no caso só estou conseguindo armazenar o id,gostaria de armazenar nickname e outras informações,alguém poderia me dar uma ajudar de como resolver esse problema.Obrigado!

- Abaixo arquivo js.

```js
var users = [];
io.on("connection", function(socket){
    console.log("User connected: ",  socket.id);
    
    socket.on("user_connected", function(username){
        socket.username = username;
        users[username] = socket.id;
        io.sockets.emit("user_connected", Object.keys(users));
    });
});
```

- Abaixo index.

```js
function enterName(){
io.emit("user_connected", idUser);
return false;
}

io.on("user_connected", function(users){
$("#lista_usuarios").empty();
$.each(users, function(indice){

opcao_usuario = ""+users[indice]+"<br />";
$("#lista_usuarios").append(opcao_usuario);
});
});
```

Comment: Muito confuso seu código, na chave **username** do array está inserindo o **id**, tbm não entendi pq não usou um `objeto` ao invés de um `array` pq terá chave e valor, aliás se fosse eu nem criaria variável alguma passaria os dados diretamente no **`emit`**, assim: **`{id: socket.id, username: socket.username}`**

Comment: No caso "users = [];" -> são os usuários que fazem login no chat com uma determinada chave,ai eu pego o id no caso que é o username e comparo com o usuário para mostrar a lista de usuários.Conseguiria me dar uma ajuda para ajustar esse código?